# Where can I find the cause of StrictMode?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to use StrictMode to prevent myself from using disk and network things in the Main Thread. Is there a way to understand these errors?

this is my LogCat which is displayed after closing my app :

[image]
[image]

Comment: Generally speaking you must look for your application in the stack traces. In this case I can't see it so it's probably something done wrong by the OS - maybe the phone manufacturer didn't properly "customise" the platform :)

Comment: Hmm I see yeah that's the reason I asked this because I couldn't find my package name and code line in the log